# How tall are the main characters in Wheel of Time?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

We know Rand is particularly tall (due to his Aiel heritage), I think Mat is also taller than average, Nynaeve is small even for a woman, and so on. But are these facts ever quantified with any sort of actual measurements?

**How tall are the major characters in the *Wheel of Time* series?**

Comment: I dunno rand al'thor, how tall ARE you?

Comment: @Broklynite Apparently, about six foot six. (In reality, I'm tall but not quite *that* tall.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Rand: **6'5"-6'6"** or **196-198 cm**.
- Mat: **5'11.5"-6'0"** or **182-183 cm**.
- Perrin: **6'1.5"-6'2"** or **187-188 cm**.
- Egwene: **5'2"-5'5"** or **157-165 cm**.
- Elayne: around **5'6"** or **168 cm**.
- Nynaeve: **5'4"-5'5"** or **163-165 cm**.
- Moiraine: **5'0"-5'3"** or **152-160 cm**.
- Aviendha: **5'8"-5'10"** or **173-178 cm**.

I'm quite surprised to learn Perrin is taller than Mat, since I'd thought the latter was described as tall while the former wasn't - but also pleased, since this matches well with how I'd *originally* imagined the characters. Other than that, nothing really surprises me: the men are taller than the women, the Aiel or half-Aiel are the tallest of each sex, and the Cairhienin woman is the shortest.

---

I found all this info by scouring the Theoryland interview database.

From [an interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=24) on 17 October 1994:

> Rand: **6'6"**
>   Perrin: **6'2"**
>   Mat: **5'11.5"**
>   Aviendha: **5'8"-5'9"**
>   Elayne: **5'6"**
>   Nynaeve: **5'4"**
>   Egwene: **5'2"**
>   Moiraine: **5'0"-5'2"**

From [another interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=40) on 26 October 1994 (emphasis mine):

> RJ gave a little height information that slightly contradicts some previous info supposedly gleaned from a signings encounter. **Rand is, of course, about 6'6". Moiraine, however, is actually as tall as 5'3", and Egwene and Nynaeve are both about 5'5".** Oh, and he said Moiraine "was" 5'3", if anyone wants to read anything into that. RJ also said that if anyone asked him how much anybody weighed, he'd throw up his hands in exasperation. I definitely got the impression that he cares nothing for the detailed heights and such, but instead goes completely from the mental pictures he's got in his head.

And just to confirm, from [another interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=20) in 1994 (date unknown; emphasis mine):

> [RJ] also gave heights for the characters. As for Rand being unusually tall, how about **6'6". Aviendha is 5'10".** You can deduce from there.

Finally, from [an interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=128) on 4 December 2000:

> Rand is **6'5" to 6'6"** and 235 lbs.
>   Perrin is **6'1½"** and 235-245 lbs.
>   Mat is **6'** and 180 lbs.

Comment: Good job, I was wondering this myself.

Answer (score -2):

No size was given. Tall Loial fit on a draft horse and in a room Rand looked as a child would to him coming just below chest he looked. Some have said RJ said this and he may have but he also said fantasy is supposed to feel larger than life I'm paraphrasing.